# take value from array and show in view

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

view :

```
<tr  style="background-color:#333; color:#FFFFFF;" align="center">
    <td>No</td>
    <td>ID TRANS</td>
    <td>NAMA</td>
    <td>TGL</td>
    <td>JUMLAH</td>
    <td>STATUS</td>
    <td>TOTAL</td>
    <td>JENIS PEL</td>
    <td>NAMA</td>
    <td>PENGELOLAAN</td>                                
</tr>
<tr class="dataku"></tr>
```

my jquery in array

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
      $(document).ready(function() {        
      selesai();
});

function selesai() {
    setTimeout(function() {

        update();
        selesai();
    }, 200);
}

function update() {

    $.getJSON("<?php echo base_url();?>transaksiDigorCont/ambilDataTransaksi", function(data) {
        alert("jhjh");
        $(".dataku").empty();
        $no=1;
        $.each(data.result, function() { 

        $(".dataku").append(

                "<td>"+$no+"</td>\n\
                <td>"+this['id_transaksi']+"</td>\n\
                <td>"+this['nama']+"</td>\n\
                <td>"+this['tgl_transaksi']+"</td>\n\
                <td>"+this['jumlah']+"</td>\n\
                <td>"+this['status_transaksi']+"</td>\n\
                <td>"+this['total']+"</td>\n\
                <td>"+this['status_pelanggan']+"</td>\n\
                <td>"+this['nama_karyawan']+"</td><td>"+this['nama_karyawan']+"</td>");
        $no++;});
    });
}
```

data.result have 3 rows, but if show in view all row show in `<td>No</td>` , I want every index is in the header title , for example : No have value $no, ID TRANS have value `this['id_transaksi']` ect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your json response is `Okay`, Put this `class="dataku"` in your your table instead of `tr`

```
<table class="dataku">

 $(".dataku").append(

            "<tr><td>"+$no+"</td>\n\
            <td>"+this['id_transaksi']+"</td>\n\
            <td>"+this['nama']+"</td>\n\
            <td>"+this['tgl_transaksi']+"</td>\n\
            <td>"+this['jumlah']+"</td>\n\
            <td>"+this['status_transaksi']+"</td>\n\
            <td>"+this['total']+"</td>\n\
            <td>"+this['status_pelanggan']+"</td>\n\
            <td>"+this['nama_karyawan']+"</td><td>"+this['nama_karyawan']+"</td></tr>");
    $no++;});
```

Comment: my table have class itself not "dataku". and each result row can change the line, i'am use <br /> but cant. result extends to the side

Comment: You need to add new `tr` every time for a new row right? So why appending the data inside a single `tr`? Add a `tr` each time for every new row. Hope you understand my point.